# Positiveness of weak solutions of a parabolic PDE

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives, parabolic-pde

Given $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a bounded smooth open set, $T>0$ and $a,b \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ and positive. I'm trying to prove the positiveness of weak solutions to the following PDE

$$
\begin{cases}
u_t-\Delta u=a(x)-b(x) u \quad \text{ in } \Omega \times(0,T), \\
u(.,0)\geq 0 \quad \text{ in } \Omega,\\
u=0 \quad\text{ on } \partial \Omega. 
\end{cases}
$$
My attempt:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt} \Vert u^- \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2&=-\int_\Omega u_t u^-\\
&=\int_\Omega -\Delta u u^--\int_\Omega a(x) u^-+\int_\Omega b(x) u u^- \quad \text{from the equation}\\
&=\int_\Omega \nabla u . \nabla u^--\int_\Omega a(x) u^-+\int_\Omega b(x) u u^- \quad \text{from Green's formula}\\
&=-\int_\Omega \vert \nabla u^- \vert^2-\int_\Omega a(x) u^-+\int_\Omega b(x) {u^-}^2 \quad \text{from the property of supports of $u$ and $u^-$}\\
&\leq\Vert b \Vert_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \Vert u^- \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 
\end{align*}
By Gronwall's inequality $u^-=0$ and the result follows.

I'm having doubts about the equality
$$
\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dt} \Vert u^- \Vert_{L^2(\Omega)}^2=-\int_\Omega u_t u^-.
$$